# No me aparecen instancias en SQL Server

Tags: sql, server

Necesito una instancia de SQL. Al momento de verificar las instancias desde CMD con OSQL -L me aparece -- NONE -- Ya verifique algunos videos de como instanciar pero no me aparece ninguna instancia ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario verificar que las instancias estén instaladas y activas. Para hacerlo, lo más sencillo es ir a servicios y buscar los servicios `SQL Server`. La instancia default aparecerá como `(MSSQLSERVER)` y las nombradas irán agregando una diagonal más el nombre. Abajo pongo un ejemplo de como se ve que existe y que está corriendo.

[image: Servicios]

Comment: Ya revise eso, me aparecia activa de igual manera la reinicie, ejecute el comando otra vez pero sigue con -- NONE --